# re.findall not returning correct results

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to return a list of MAC addresses from some sample text. `re.search` returns the first result, and in this instance I want all results, but I only get one. When I use `re.findall`, it returns the last character from each MAC address instead of the full addresses.

Any ideas?

For example:

```
>>> test = """
...           Mac Address Table
... -------------------------------------------
...
... Vlan    Mac Address       Type        Ports
... ----    -----------       --------    -----
...   66    0800.0e54.9df0    STATIC      Gi2/0/27
...  100    5046.5a08.5a60    STATIC      Gi2/0/27
... Total Mac Addresses for this criterion: 2
... """
macs = re.search(r"([0-9A-Fa-f]){4}\.([0-9A-Fa-f]){4}\.([0-9A-Fa-f]){4}",test)
>>> print macs.group()
0800.0f54.99f0
macs = re.findall(r"([0-9A-Fa-f]){4}\.([0-9A-Fa-f]){4}\.([0-9A-Fa-f]){4}",test)
[('0', '4', '0'), ('6', '8', '0')]
```

Comment: Remove all the capturing groups. `macs = re.findall(r"[0-9A-Fa-f]{4}\.[0-9A-Fa-f]{4}\.[0-9A-Fa-f]{4}",test)`

Comment: Thanks! do you want to add that as answer so i can accept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) documentation:

> If one or more groups are present in the pattern, return a list of groups; this will be a list of tuples if the pattern has more than one group. Empty matches are included in the result unless they touch the beginning of another match.

So, turn all *capturing* groups into *non-capturing* or remove them if possible (here, it is best to remove them as they are just redundant):

```
macs = re.findall(r"[0-9A-Fa-f]{4}\.[0-9A-Fa-f]{4}\.[0-9A-Fa-f]{4}"‌​,test)
```

Comment: this is not the good way to fix the problem because it do not anwser to question and do not fix what is wrong, just bypass it.

Comment: @Arount: Look: *I'm trying to return a list of MAC addresses* - that is exactly what this solution does.

Comment: You are right, sorry, my bad. But the part of python doc and what you recommend gives the impression re.findall do not suport capturing groups which is wrong. I can't remove my downvote, if you edit your awser I may.

Comment: @Arount: First, you are wrong. Second, I do not care about downvotes, it is a Wiki answer, you may edit it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Other awnsers recommend to remove capturing groups, but that is not what you want and this not how to solve the issue.

> re.findall(pattern, string, flags=0)
>
> Return all non-overlapping matches of pattern in string, as a list of strings. The string is scanned left-to-right, and matches are returned in the order found. If one or more groups are present in the pattern, return a list of groups; this will be a list of tuples if the pattern has more than one group. Empty matches are included in the result unless they touch the beginning of another match.

The real problem is capturing groups are wrong here, I past the good pattern first, then the one used to check diffs easily:

```
([0-9A-Fa-f]{4})\.([0-9A-Fa-f]{4})\.([0-9A-Fa-f]{4}) # good one
([0-9A-Fa-f]){4}\.([0-9A-Fa-f]){4}\.([0-9A-Fa-f]){4} # bad one
```

As you can see, if you capture all the alphanumeric string composed by 4 characters (`([CHARS]{4})` and not `([CHARS]){4}` you capture all the string part in one group, so `re.findall` will capture characters groups and not only characters one by one.

Because you was capturing characters one by one and `findall` return **non-overlapping** matches you got this result.

Result with good pattern:

```
[('0800', '0e54', '9df0'), ('5046', '5a08', '5a60')]
```

Comment: OP does not need the list of tuples containing hex char chunks, only *a list of MAC addresses*.